# "synapses grow closer together in order to decrease the distance", is it true?

Tags: brain

Is there a source?

That synapses get physically get close as their interaction increases.

I have also read that where neurons crosses each other they create new neuron, is that true?

Comment: 1. What do you mean with interaction? Synaptic mechanisms? 2. No, as new neurons are born only in restricted areas of the nervous system.

Comment: I think you're talking about [Hebbian theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hebbian_theory)? My neuro professor used to summarize this as "Cells that fire together, wire together" (although apparently he was in fact quoting [Carla Shatz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carla_J._Shatz)).

Comment: http://www.curiousapes.com/the-science-of-happiness-why-complaining-is-literally-killing-you/

Comment: " the synapses grow closer together in order to decrease the distance the electrical charge has to cross. "

Comment: The first red flag is that this sentence is incorrect, based on the explanation following it in the source you linked. It suggests that there would be a reduced distance from one synapse to the next, while the text really explains that there will be a reduction in the width of the synaptic cleft. I am not certain enough to give an answer, but the sloppy language alone makes me think the author does not know what he's talking about.